# Multiplative subgroup of lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let's start with subalgebra $A \subset GL(N, R)$ with commutator as Lie bracket. It has subset of invertable elements which form group $G$.

I want to proof (if it's true of course)

1. $G$ is Lie group
2. Lie algebra of $G$ is $A$

Comment: I don't understand this question. Lie algebras don't have invertible elements, as x^2 = 0 for all elements x. However, if you mean in the underlying associative algebra, then every element is invertible.

Comment: Ye, i mean underlying associative algebra. Why it should be invertible? E.g. $GL(N, Z)$ is not such algebra, but produce lie algebra via commutator.

Comment: I assumed that you meant by GL(N,R) the set of invertible N X N matrices over the real numbers.

Comment: Yeap, seems like you're right, sorry. So basically $G$ is just $A$ without $\{0\}$. But what's then about second part?